# MVC3 fails to parse JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Using the following action from a MVC3 controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetAsiguratiSuplimentari(int numarAsiguratiSuplimentari, AcpComplexAsigurat[] oldData)
        {
            var newData = new List<AcpComplexAsigurat>(oldData);
            for(int i = newData.Count; i < numarAsiguratiSuplimentari; i++)
            {
                newData.Add(new AcpComplexAsigurat());
            }
            return PartialView("AsiguratiSuplimentari", newData);
        }
```

and the js:

```
  $("#NumarAsiguratiSuplimentari").change(function (e) {
            var data = { oldData: $("#div-asigurati-suplimentari").find('input').serialize(), numarAsiguratiSuplimentari: $("#NumarAsiguratiSuplimentari").val() };
            var postData = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.post('@Url.Action("GetAsiguratiSuplimentari")', postData, function (data) {
                $("#div-asigurati-suplimentari").html(data);
            });
        });
```

I want to get the select option the user chose and serialize a table of inputs to send to the above action:

```
  <h3>Asigurati</h3>
            <div class="field half odd">
                <label>Numar asigurati suplimentari</label>
                <select id="NumarAsiguratiSuplimentari" name="NumarAsiguratiSuplimentari">
                    @for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i" @(Model.Asigurati.Count == i ? "selected" : "")>@i</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field full" id="div-asigurati-suplimentari">
                @if (Model.Asigurati.Count > 0)
                {
    <table id="Asigurati">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CNP</th>
                <th>Nume</th>
                <th>Prenume</th>
                <th>Data nasterii</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Asigurati)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 3px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Asigurati[Model.Asigurati.IndexOf(item)].Cnp, new { maxlength = 13 })</td>
                    <td style="padding: 3px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Asigurati[Model.Asigurati.IndexOf(item)].Nume)</td>
                    <td style="padding: 3px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Asigurati[Model.Asigurati.IndexOf(item)].Prenume)</td>
                    <td style="padding: 3px;">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Asigurati[Model.Asigurati.IndexOf(item)].DataNastere)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
                }
            </div>
```

In monorail, I would have had to decorate the input parameters with a {JsonBinder] attribute, but in MVC3 i am not sure how to proceed.

It basically gives me the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'numarAsiguratiSuplimentari' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetAsiguratiSuplimentari(Int32,
>   BrokerPlatform.Services.AcpComplex.AcpComplexAsigurat[])' in
>   'BrokerPlatform.Areas.AcpComplex.Controllers.CarpaticaController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Here is the JSON that it sends:

> {"numarAsiguratiSuplimentari":"2","oldData":""}

Comment: Can you add the raw JSON being sent?

Comment: what line do you exactly get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are inconsistent.

```
public ActionResult GetAsiguratiSuplimentari(int numarAsiguratiSuplimentari?, AcpComplexAsigurat[] oldData)
```

`int? numarAsiguratiSuplimentari` is nullable `?`

or

```
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetAsiguratiSuplimentari")', {numarAsiguratiSuplimentari:number,AcpComplexAsigurat:list}, function (data) {
```

...`{numarAsiguratiSuplimentari:number,AcpComplexAsigurat:list}`....

You can parse the string and get the json, and convert to model.

My sample;

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult GetAsiguratiSuplimentari(string model)
{
    List<myModel> myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<muModel>>(model);
}
```

Comment: the variable numarAsiguratiSuplimentari is always there. It shouldn't be nullable. As for your "or", i'm not sure i understand....

Comment: `...int numarAsiguratiSuplimentari?,...` is not valid syntax.

Comment: `...int? numarAsiguratiSuplimentari,...` this true, sorry @PLB

Comment: Well, I'd rather use the model binding MVC3 brings to the table, than deserializing the input manually. Harder to make unit tests that way.

Comment: @Cosmo D The value of numarAsiguratiSuplimentari in PostData?

Comment: I've checked firebug, and yeah, it is.

Comment: I don't know If there is another method. I doing like the example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MVC 3 right now, but this is working fine with MVC 4 (using Fiddler). There are a few things you can try:

- Explicitly set `dataType: "json"` in the `$.post` call, jQuery might not be able to guess it.
- Change the method signature to accept a `string` instead of an `int`, the binding in MVC 3 might not be able to do it automatically.

If one of these work, let me know so I can remove the incorrect option.